# !FIXED! How do you send a message in a channel on startup in discord.js"

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

**Fixed elsewhere.**
I'm currently coding a discord.js bot and when the bot starts it will send a message in a certain channel. How do you do that?

I know this might sound stupid but I'm quite new to discord.js. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add more context around what code you've already written, where in the code you think the error is happening and what you'e tried to resolve the issue. See the following link for information about how to properly structure a question on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
client.on("ready", () => {
    const Channel = client.channels.cache.get("ChannelID");
    if (!Channel) return console.log("Invalid channel.");

    Channel.send("Bot startup.");
});
```

Comment: Gives me a `ReferenceError: client is not defined` error.

Comment: Change `client` to the variable that holds your Discord client.

Comment: There is another `client` variable that you need to change. `**client**.channels.cache`

Comment: You mean `**client**.channel.cache`? (Edit: OK)